# always block with no sensitivity list - $display not executed

Tags: verilog, digital-design

When I run the following Verilog code I get an error:

> warning: @* found no sensitivities so it will never trigger.

```
module main;
  
  reg b;
  always @(*) begin
    
    $display("entered always block/n");
  end
  
endmodule
```

Could someone please elaborate on this? Is there any way I can use `$display` without "sensitivity list"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your simulator is correctly warning you of an unusual situation.  That `$display` statement will never be executed.  Hence, it is useless code.

The implicit sensitivity list (`@*`) means that it will only be entered if some signal (like `b`) changes value, and it is used on the right-hand side (RHS) of some expression inside the `always`.  The problem is that you do not have any signal inside your block.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 9.4.2.2 *Implicit event_expression list*.

If you add `b` to your trivial example, the `always` block will be triggered if there is any change on `b`:

```
module main;
  
  reg b;
  always @(*) begin
    $display("entered always block and b=%b", b);
  end

initial begin
    b=0;
    #50 $finish;
end

always #5 b = ~b;
    
endmodule
```

Outputs:

```
entered always block and b=0
entered always block and b=1
entered always block and b=0
entered always block and b=1
entered always block and b=0
entered always block and b=1
entered always block and b=0
entered always block and b=1
entered always block and b=0
entered always block and b=1
```

Runnable example on [edaplayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2p3U).

Answer (score 0):

The `always` construct introduces a procedural sequence of code that loops endlessly. It must have at least one procedural blocking construct, otherwise it gets into an infinite zero-delay loop. And that prevents anything else from executing.

The intended use of `always` is to wait for some signal to change, or wait for some time delay. But if you only want the `$display` to execute once, use `initial` instead of `always` and it will start executing the procedural sequence once at time 0, and not loop.